# Can some one help me on this one?

Tags: web-scraping

Hi Can i get some help I get titre is not define error

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re

 url = "https://www.centris.ca/Property/GetInscriptions"
 headers = {
         "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 
                                                                             Firefox/89.0",
           }
 json_data = {"startPosition": 0}

   with requests.session() as s:
Centris = []
# load cookies:
s.get(
    "https://www.centris.ca/en/commercial-units~for-rent?uc=0",
    headers=headers,
)
for page in range(0, 100, 20):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    json_data["startPosition"] = page

    data = s.post(url, headers=headers, json=json_data).json()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data["d"]["Result"]["html"], "html.parser")

    for a in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id':'divMainResult'}):

        
        titre = a.find('span', attrs={'data-id': 'PageTitle'}).get_text(strip=True)
        
        emplacement = a.find_all('h2', attrs={'class': 'pt-1'}).get_text(strip=True, separator="\n")
        
        lien = "https://www.centris.ca" + a["href"]
        
        prix = a.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'text-nowrap'}).get_text(strip=True)
        
        superficie = a.find('div', attrs={'class': 'carac-value'}, string=re.compile('sqft')).get_text(strip=True)

        Centris.append((titre, emplacement, lien, prix))


df = pd.DataFrame(Centris, columns={'Titre':titre, 'Emplacement':emplacement, 'Lien':lien, 
                                                     'Prix':prix, 'Superficie': superficie })


      writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Centris4.xlsx')

      df.to_excel(writer)

      writer.save()

      print( 'Data Saved To excel' )
```

When I run this code I get name titre not define i cant find where the error is.
any help would be much appreciated, also will this code be able to scrape multiple page?

Comment: Guessing that the length of `soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id':'divMainResult'})` is zero. If that's the case, `titre` is never assigned.

Comment: It might help people find your question if you update the post title to describe the problem.